# Very simple Java Dynamic Casting

Tags: java, dynamic, casting

Simple question but I have spent over an hour with this. My code is below. I need to make SomeClass sc dynamic. So you pass the class name  as a string in a function and use that class in place of static someClass. How to go about it?

```
SomeClass sc;
if (someOtherClassObject instanceof SomeClass){
    sc=(SomeClass) someOtherClassObject;
```

What I want is

```
public void castDynamic (String strClassName){
  //cast the classname referred by strClassName to SomeClass 
  //if it is the  instance of SomeClass
}
```

EDIT:
The above was simplification. The actual code is this

```
public void X(String className, RequestInterface request)
{
    //My current code is this, I need to change so that "XRequest"
    //can be any   class referred by "className", 
    //and "request.getRequest" the object belonging to "className" class
    //I don't want static XRequest xvr, it should be fetched dynamically

    XRequest xvr;
    if (request.getRequest() instanceof XRequest){
        xvr=(XRequest) request.getRequest();
        client.setRequest(xvr); 
    }
}
```

Another simple rephrase: I get an object using request.getRequest(). I have no clue what that object is. So I need to cast it to the classstring name provided. How to do that? That's all. – SQC 13 mins ago

Comment: Perhaps you should describe your desired result in your question.  Creating an instance of a class based on a string has nothing to do with dynamic casting.  Do you want to create an instance of a known class starting with a string class name or do you want to create an instance of any class starting with a string class name?

Comment: please see updated question (even if it's a bit confusing). What I am creating is an api call which receives classname, and an object  of the same classname. I need to cast the object to the classname in the method (but remember I have only the string for classname, not the real class). That's all. Simple.

Comment: The proper way would be to put that Method into the `RequestInterface`, then you can easily call it. Other than that, you need to use **reflection** to retrieve a method to invoke.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to *instantiate* a class by it's name?

First of all, you need to make a `Class<?>` object:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(strClassName);
```

Then instantiate this (note, this can throw various exceptions - access violation, `ClassNotFound`, no *public* constructor without arguments etc.)

```
Object instance = cls.newInstance();
```

Then you can cast it:

```
return (SomeClass) instance;
```

Please make sure you understand the differences between:

1. A class **name** (approximately a file name)
2. A class **object** (essentially a *type* information)
3. A class **instance** (an actual object of this type)

You can also cast the `cls` object to have type `Class<? extends SomeClass>`, if you want. It doesn't give you much, though. And you can inline it, to:

```
return (SomeClass)(Class.forName(strClassName).newInstance());
```

Oh, but you *can* do type checking with the `cls` object, before instantiating it. So you only instanciate it, if it satisfies your API (implements the interface you want to get).

EDIT: add further example code, towards **reflection**.

For example:

```
if (cls.isInstance(request)) {
  // ...
}
```

For invoking methods, you either need to know an interface that you can cast to, or use **reflection** (the `getMethod` methods of the `cls` object):

```
Method getRequest = cls.getMethod("getRequest");
getRequest.invoke(request);
```

Comment: Works the same: `cls.isInstance(request)`

Answer (score 7):

The problem you're describing is not well defined.
Casting is an operation that takes an object and a Class and then checks if that object is an instance of the given class.

However you're saying you need something that `cast(s) the classname referred by strClassName to SomeClass if it is the  instance of SomeClass`. In other words, you're looking something that works on two classes (rather than a class and an object).

So, we need to restate the problem. Here are three possible problems (+ solutions) I'm hoping one of them is what you need

```
// Problem 1: check whether "object" can be casted to the class 
// whose name is "className"
public void castDynamic(Object object, String className) {
  Class cls = Class.forName(className);
  cls.cast(object);
}

// Problem 2: check whether the class whose name is "className" 
// is a subclass of SomeClass (A is a subclass of B if A (transitively) 
// extends or implements B).
public void castDynamic(String className) {
  Class cls = Class.forName(className);
  SomeClass.class.asSubclass(cls);
}


// Problem 3: check whether SomeClass is a sublcass the class 
// whose name is "className"
public void castDynamic(String className) {
  Class cls = Class.forName(className);
  cls.asSubclass(SomeClass.class);
}
```

Full details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass(java.lang.Class)

Comment: Thanks. please see my original question and comments therein on what I want

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?

```
 Class clazz = Class.forName(strClassName);
```

Comment: Th error is caused by the two lines below that cast. How would you code the "if (){}" part?

Comment: What is your end goal?  When you cast objects this way its because you need to use an instance of that class for something.