# Implementing a Generic Method using Cast and Generics

Tags: java, generics, jaxb

I read the posts:
- [Very simple Java Dynamic Casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479943/very-simple-java-dynamic-casting)
- [java: how can i do dynamic casting of a variable from one type to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127318/java-how-can-i-do-dynamic-casting-of-a-variable-from-one-type-to-another)

But it did not answer exactly what I was looking for.
I need to create a method that creates a class from a XML inside a String.  The XSD is created and I use JAXB with success to marshall/unmarshall the XML to Class and back.  But this is too static.  The code below is the actual code.

```
    public static SaiRenovacao createClassFromString(String string,
            Class Response) throws JAXBException {
        SaiRenovacao _return = null;
```

```
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(string);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Object temp = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    _return = (SaiRenovacao) temp;
    return _return;
}
```

I wanna change this method.  I need/would like to pass a Class by parameter 'Response' and my code must instantiate this Class [JAXBContext.newInstance(Response);] and unmarshall it and return the unmarshalled class - that is the class passed as parameter in Response - to the caller.

The way it is written I can only work with SaiRenovacao class.

If I change the implementation to I will get an obvious Exception because I can not resolve Response to a type.  But this is the basic idea of what I need to do.

```
    public static SaiRenovacao createClassFromString(String retorno,
            Class Response) throws JAXBException {
        SaiRenovacao _retorno = null;
```

```
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(retorno);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Object temp = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    _retorno = (Response) temp;
    return _retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
return clazz.cast(temp);
```

And change your method signature to

```
public static <T> T createClassFromString(String retorno, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
```

Comment: I think you just mean `clazz.cast(temp);` since `clazz.getClass()` will return `Class.class`.